# Gradle run failed on multi module micronaut project

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle, micronaut

I have a below project structure

[image]

Project product and API gateway share the common project as common.
Since in the settings.gradle I have include the project as below

```
rootProject.name = 'src'
include 'common', 'fetebird-apigateway', 'fete-bird-product'
```

In the API gateway build.gradle I have include the below dependency

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':common')
    }
```

In the product build.gradle I have include the below dependency\

```
    plugins {
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "6.0.0"
    id "io.micronaut.application" version '1.0.3'
}

version "0.1"
group "fete.bird"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

micronaut {
    runtime "netty"
    testRuntime "junit5"
    processing {
        incremental true
        annotations "fete.bird.*"
    }
}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut.openapi:micronaut-openapi")
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-processor")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")
    implementation("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    implementation("io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-discovery-client")
    implementation("io.micronaut.rxjava3:micronaut-rxjava3")
    implementation("io.micronaut.kafka:micronaut-kafka")
    implementation("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-hibernate-jpa")
    implementation("io.micronaut.mongodb:micronaut-mongo-reactive")
    testImplementation("de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo:2.0.1")
    implementation project(':common')
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
}

mainClassName = "fete.bird.ProductApplication"
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion('15')
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion('15')
}
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.fork = true
    options.forkOptions.jvmArgs << '-Dmicronaut.openapi.views.spec=rapidoc.enabled=true,swagger-ui.enabled=true,swagger-ui.theme=flattop'
}
```

**common.buid.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'fete.bird'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Product main class

```
public class ProductApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Micronaut.run(ProductApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

when I run the individual project with command line or intellj idea

```
$ gradle build
```

or

```
$ gradle run
```

Exception

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file '/Users/macbook/Projects/FeteBird-Microservice/src/fete-bird-product/build.gradle' line: 37

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'fete-bird-product'.
> Project with path ':common' could not be found in root project 'fete-bird-product'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'fete-bird-product'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Cannot query the value of extension 'application' property 'mainClass' because it has no value available.
   > Cannot query the value of extension 'application' property 'mainClass' because it has no value available.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================
```

The issue is with `Project with path ':common' could not be found in root project 'fete-bird-product'.`

Comment: do you have import for 'application' in your common build.gradle?

Comment: @IEE1394 added the build.gradle for the common project, please have a look

Comment: that seems fine, do you have a mainClassName in your product build.gradle?

Comment: I have update the question with whole dependency, I do have mainClassName = "fete.bird.ProductApplication" in the gradle.build

Comment: i also struggle with the new micronaut gradle plugin and multi module projects, have you tried the exactly same setup in a single module project?

Comment: For single module everything works fine

Comment: so eighter get back to the old 2.X application style without the new gradle module and/or file an issue on github

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your project structure is slightly incorrect. The root build.gradle should be in the root of the project, not in `src`.

I have created this [repo](https://github.com/abedurftig/gradle-kts-buildsrc) some time ago, which leverages a multi-module setup. You can ignore the BuildSrc module if you want.

```
.
├── build.gradle.kts
├── moduleA
│   └── build.gradle.kts
├── moduleB
│   └── build.gradle.kts
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
└── settings.gradle.kts
```